# react organizing links in render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found a [tutorial](https://github.com/jzabala/react-redux-by-rem-zolotykh/blob/master/client/src/components/NavigationBar.js) where navigation bar links are displayed as per a `const` field created within the `render()` method. While the code works great, I am trying to do a bit more.

If the user is **Super admin** (lets say), I would like to display both `superAdminLinks` as well as `userLinks`. I tried multiple things, but I am not able to get this thing right. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

My `render()` code snippet, looks like below

```
render() {


            const isSuperAdmin = user.user_role === "SUPER_ADMIN";


            const userLeftMenu = (
                <ul className="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li>UserLink1</li>
                    <li>UserLink2</li>
                </ul>
            )

            const superAdminLeftMenu = (
                <ul className="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li>SuperAdminLink1</li>
                    <li><SuperAdminLink2</li>
                </ul>
            )

            return (
                    <header>
                        <div className="container-fluid">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                                 { isSuperAdmin ? superAdminLeftMenu : userLeftMenu  }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   </header>
            );
    }
```

Above code only renders SuperAdminLinks if the user is SuperAdmin. How can I render, both user and super admin links for SuperUser?

Comment: Even if you have already found a solution to the problem, take a look at my answer, I think it may interest you for future applications to be able to return several div within the same `if`. I hope you find it useful, regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div className="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
   { isSuperAdmin ? superAdminLeftMenu : userLeftMenu  }
   { isSuperAdmin && userLeftMenu  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const role = "SUPER_ADMIN";

const App = () => {
  const isSuperAdmin = role === "SUPER_ADMIN";

  const userLeftMenu = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <li>UserLink1</li>
      <li>UserLink2</li>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  const superAdminLeftMenu = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <li>SuperAdminLink1</li>
      <li>SuperAdminLink2</li>
      {userLeftMenu}
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  return (
    <header>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul className="nav nav-sidebar">
              {isSuperAdmin ? superAdminLeftMenu : userLeftMenu}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: awesome. this will be better readable once logic gets bit complicated

Comment: Althogh @Subin 's answer solved my issue. This looks much more organized and cleaner approach. I am going to implement this :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
return (
   <header>
     <div className="container-fluid">
       <div className="row">
         <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
           { isSuperAdmin && superAdminLeftMenu }
           { isSuperAdmin && userLeftMenu }   
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </header>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If not is the case of `UserLeftMenu` is always inside `SuperUserLeftMenu`, then we can use one better way to do this. This form lets return all components you want inside same `if` statement:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const role = "SUPER_ADMIN";

const App = () => {
  const isSuperAdmin = role === "SUPER_ADMIN";

  const UserLeftMenu = () => (
      <div>
          <li>UserLink1</li>
          <li>UserLink2</li>
      </div>
  );

  const SuperAdminLeftMenu = () => (
      <div>
          <li>SuperAdminLink1</li>
          <li>SuperAdminLink2</li>
      </div>
  );

  return (
<header>
    <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                { isSuperAdmin 
                        ? <div>
                              <SuperAdminLeftMenu/>
                              <UserLeftMenu/>
                          </div> 
                          /* 
                             Return 'SuperAdminLeftMenu' and 'UserLeftMenu' 
                             components. If you returns components of this 
                             form, you can return all component you want 
                             inside same if
                           */
                        : <UserLeftMenu /> 
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
);
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

If `UserLeftMenu` is always inside `SuperUserLeftMenu`, you can do something like:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const role = "SUPER_ADMIN";

const App = () => {
  const isSuperAdmin = role === "SUPER_ADMIN";

  const UserLeftMenu = () => (
      <div>
          <li>UserLink1</li>
          <li>UserLink2</li>
      </div>
  );

  const SuperAdminLeftMenu = () => (
      <div>
          <li>SuperAdminLink1</li>
          <li>SuperAdminLink2</li>
          { <UserLeftMenu/> } 
      </div> // Include 'UserLeftMenu' inside 'SuperAdminLeftMenu'
  );

  return (
<header>
    <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                { isSuperAdmin 
                        ? <SuperAdminLeftMenu/> // Return 'SuperAdminLeftMenu' component
                        : <UserLeftMenu /> 
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
);
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```